# Alternativas a "irretrasable"

Tags: sinónimos, adjetivos

La vicepresidenta del Gobierno de España dijo recientemente "medidas irretrasables" que no existe en el español. Yo encuentro como sinónimos medidas inaplazables, medidas de imposible retraso. ¿Qué otras alternativas existen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La palabra que primero se me ocurre es ["impostergable"](http://www.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=impostergable). Pero hay otras palabras afines: inaplazable, urgente, perentorio, improrrogable, ineludible.

Comment: De hecho parece ser que es un término bastante exacto con lo que quiso decir.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: Lo malo es que habiendo tantas opciones que existen en la lengua, tuvo que usar una que no existe.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: Sí, "irretrasable" no existe y encima suena mal.

Comment: Bueno utilizó otro que no existe, por ejemplo trabajo de bolillos, puede ser que estuviera intentando hacerse entender por el pueblo llano. Lo cual denota que piensa que el pueblo llano es imbécil.

Comment: No es que suene mal es que escandaliza (;

Comment: Yo creo que su primo le hace los discursos, vamos, la misma historia de siempre, el primo enchufado, que no tiene estudios :D

Answer (score 2):

Mi primera opción sería *inaplazable*, también es bastante común.

---

*Inaplazable* would be my first option, it's also pretty common.

Comment: El idioma principal del sitio es el castellano, es preferible contestar en inglés sólo cuando se pregunte originalmente en inglés.